# how can i draw multiple lines in layout that save the previous drawn lines?

Tags: android, graphics

i have drawn a line using paint and canvas and draw method.
But now line is drawn successfully.
But when i am going to draw second line than it will erase the previously drawn lines.
and start drawing a new line.

Comment: Could you paste your code here that does the drawing?

Comment: ya i will but it will not provide me edit option to my question because i am just new to this....so what to do for paste the code..

Answer (score 1):

To store the lines drawn, and enable the user to manipulate them, is only moderately complex, in my opinion.

Create a Line class.  Include the start and end co-ordinates, colour etc as fields of the class and methods to delete, move etc.  Also add a method which takes a MotionEvent argument.  In this method, you use the MotionEvent to determine if this line has been touched and adjust it's position as you need.

Store references to each line drawn (created as an instance of the Line class) in a collection or list of some sort in your extended View class, ArrayList should do.  Then, in the onTouch event, call the touch detect method of each line and pass the MotionEvent to the methods.

Finally, override the onDraw callback of the View to draw each line by iterating through the collection of references to the Line instances.

You could also add more gesture such as long press for delete etc.  Here's a (totally untested, written from memory) skeleton of such an approach.

```
class Line

    public float x1, x2, y1, y2;

    public void detectTouch(MotionEvent motionEvent){

         // code to detect a touch and adjust the x and ys accordingly

    }

class DrawView extends View{

    private ArrayList<Line> lines = new ArrayList<Lines>();

    ....
    ....

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        super.onDraw();

        for (Line line : lines){
             canvas.drawLine(line.x1,line.y1,line.x2,line.y2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {

        ....
        ....

        for (Line line : lines){
            line.detectTouch(MotionEvent);
        }


    }
```

Have fun!

Comment: thanx...but can u please post all the code with xml layout ??

Comment: Are you asking how to add a custom `View` to a layout?

Comment: not custom view but when user touch screen and draw line so it will allow to draw multiple line and also show previous drawn lines....because right now when i m drawing line it will allow but not show previous one direct draw new..

Comment: `i want solution for that`.  No-one is going to write your code for you.  I have given you all that you need to do it.

Comment: i have already done it but only problem is that not show previous drawn line.

Comment: Hmmm, I think you are missing something.  The solution I have given will draw the new line plus all of the previous lines. That's why the `for` loop enumerates the lines collection. It is exactly what you asked for.